# Site does not update after publish

Tags: azure

I am publishing the site using VS 2012 Publish website option. But the site does not get updated. I have to restart the website from manage.windowsazure.com every time after publishing.

I have been running the website on both free and shared mode. Same situation in both mode.

Any suggestion how to update the website automatically after publish?

Comment: Hi oazabir did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Mmm. If your change regards CSS and JavaScript, try browse your website by using Ctrl+F5. If it seems totally not being updated, you might need to check the deployment page of your website on azure portal to see if it's get updated or not, or something wrong.

HTH